# How to get user from multilevel array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array from DB.

Now I want to get shin in  `[user] => shin`.

How can I get it with PHP?

Number in `[29] => Array` could be any number.

Thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
    [29] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [day] => 29
                    [eventContent] => school ski tada
                    [eventTitle] => school ski
                    [id] => 24
                    [user] => shin
                    [user_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [day] => 29
                    [eventContent] => north again
                    [eventTitle] => ski hello
                    [id] => 26
                    [user] => shin
                    [user_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [day] => 31
                    [eventContent] => test
                    [eventTitle] => test
                    [id] => 21
                    [user] => shin
                    [user_id] => 1
                )

        )
...
...

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the array indexes represent but I'll leave them in just in case they're useful to you.  The answer is basically the same as Alix's with a check to ensure you actually have a nested array:

```
foreach ($array as $day => $events) {
    if (is_array($events)) {
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            echo $day;         // outputs 29 (same as $event->day)
            echo $event->user; // outputs shin
            echo $event->eventContent;
            echo $event->eventTitle;
            echo $event->id;
            // etc, etc, etc.
        }
    } 
}
```

Notice the difference between the outer foreach loop and the inner loop.  The outer one is retrieving both the array key *and* value whereas the inner loop is only returning the array value.

Comment: foreach outputs the same number of users. How can I output only one. I want to echo "This is Shin's calendar". If there are three events, it will output three times.

Comment: You can `break` (http://php.net/break) after the first one, or use `current` instead.

Answer (score 1):

See [`current`](http://php.net/current):

> The current() function simply returns the value of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer.

and all it's *See also*-s (`end`, `each`, `key`, `prev`, `reset`, `next`).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($yourArray as $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $object)
    {
        echo $object->user;
    }
}
```